# Can I deprecate usage of specific class (not under our control) in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

Does Android Studio's inspection feature contain some option to mark certain classes as deprecated?

I suppose that the inspection rules currently do not support parametrized inspections e.g. "Mark following classes as deprecated: _______" but is there another way to fix that?

I want to move away from class `X` (which is not under our control) and use class `XExtended` and would like to reliably ensure that in our codebase no-one uses `X` again. Since we do use inspections regularly, having an inspection which looks for certain classes mark them as warning or error would be very useful.

Search and replace is somewhat tedious and does not protect for new uses. I also cannot remove the library where `X` is located as it is part of the android sdk.

Edit: During refactoring we find all those old uses due to unit test failures but not everything is yet fully covered with tests, so there might be undetected issues.

Comment: You could write a custom Lint check for this. I don't know if custom inspections are a thing. I'm fairly certain that the deprecation inspection is looking for `@Deprecated`, which isn't an option in your case.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, I am looking into it but it looks like writing a lint extension is neither trivial nor a quick task to do.

Comment: There is definitely a learning curve, compounded by the fact that it is all largely undocumented, particularly given a twice-overhauled API. [This blog post](https://medium.com/@vanniktech/writing-your-first-lint-check-39ad0e90b9e6) is close, IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. I managed to do it with Android Studio 3.1.1. I marked a `WebView` class as deprecated as follows:

[image: Deprecate class]

Then whenever I try to use `WebView` it will display deprecated as follows:
[image: deprecated]

Steps to deprecate:

1. Click on the class which you want to deprecate.
2. Yellow bulb icon will appear at left
3. Expand it and click on `Annotate class <Class> as @Deprecated`

Through out the project, this class will be deprecated.

Comment: Wonderful, exactly the thing I was looking for!

Comment: @Samuel Great! Good know it was useful